# Opencart White Blank Page After installing a module

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed a opencart module by using extension installer. After instal the module I have faced white blank page. I check the error.log and I have tried to write a few code in both index.php and php.ini but i can't see the error. Also ,I tried to clean this module in to my root but result is same. Please help me what can i do to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. While I was trying to edit index.php and php.ini , error did not display. I edit the startup.php which is under system folder and add the following code below the

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

ini_set('log_errors', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);'

Then the error display and I fixed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
Login Admin Side Go in 
System->Setting->Edit after Find Server Tab Click
after find out "Display Errors" set  "Yes" save
```

Comment: contact phpscript3@gmail.com